# Using a user-defined type as map value in c++

Tags: c++, gcc, stdmap

I'm new to C++ programming and got a problem with using the std::map class.
I want to map an int value to a self-defined type. The map should contain the actual value and not a pointer to it!
Example:
I want to do this:`map<int,Type>` and not this: `map<int,Type*>`.

What i tried is:

```
map<int,Type> myMap;
myMap.insert(make_pair(keyVal,Type(intVal,intVal,intVal))); //Type takes 3 int-values for construction.
myMap[intVal].useMemberFunction();
```

The error message is

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Type::Type()’ second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)

`Type` is my user-defined type.  Is it possible to instantiate an object like this, or do i have to use the `new` operator in some way?
How can i make this work?
I searched the web for it but all i found was using a user-defined type as key, which is not what i want to do.

Comment: *"Is it possible to instantiate an object like this"*? Have you tried?

Comment: I have but i keep getting errors.

Comment: And you think you should not show the Type and the error messages?

Comment: I don't see any errors in your post. Since you just joined [so], please take the [tour], visit the [help], and read [ask]. You need to post a [mcve] for people to be able to help you.

Comment: @Gotsiller In addition to what has been said - did you try _reading_ the error messages? They typically state exactly what's wrong.

Comment: The error message is:
error: no matching function for call to ‘Gate::Gate()’
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
Gate is the selfe-defined type.

Comment: Don't post details in comments. Rather, [edit] your post and add them in, preferably after cleanly formatting them. Please read the material in the links I gave you.

Comment: @Gotsiller also, show us the error from the [mcve] where you had named the type `Type`; not an error from some code that we've not seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to instantiate an object like this

Yes, it is.

> or do i have to use the new operator in some way?

No, you don't.

> How can i make this work?

That already works, assuming you define the variables and types that were missing from the example:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
using std::map;
using std::make_pair;

struct Type {
    Type(int,int,int){}
    Type(){}
    void useMemberFunction(){}
};

int main() {
    int keyVal = 0, intVal = 0;
    map<int,Type> myMap;
    myMap.insert(make_pair(keyVal,Type(intVal,intVal,intVal))); //Type takes 3 int-values for construction.
    myMap[intVal].useMemberFunction();
}
```

One note though: As per documentation, `std::map::operator[]` requires that the value type is default constructible. If the type is not default constructible, then you cannot use the subscript operator. You can use `std::map::at` or `std::map::find` instead.

Comment: `std::map::at` is closer in usage to `std::map::operator[]` than `std::map::find `

Comment: @Caleth good point, it's a better choice here. I'll keep the mention of find, since it's better alternative to subscript operator in other situations.

Comment: The type is not defaul constructible. I used `map.find(val)->second.useMemberFunction();` now and it works.
Thank you!